# gmaps4rails : HOW do I set map options such as container ID for a directions map?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I have been trying to set my container class and id options for a directions maps without any success... anyone knows how to?

From documentation:

```
<%= gmaps( :map_options => { :container_class => "foo", :id => "bar", :class => "baz" } %>

<%= gmaps({"direction" => { "data" => { "from" => "Paris, france", "to" => "Toulon, france" } }})
 %>
```

I tried combining both but it just won't work...

Cheers,

Joel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only want a single map right?

In this case:

```
<%= gmaps( :map_options => { :container_class => "foo", :id => "bar", :class => "baz" },
           "direction" => { "data" => { "from" => "Paris, france", "to" => "Toulon, france" }}
) %>
```